# Run private sub in Visio

Tags: vba, visio

I wrote two macros in MS Visio. The first macro hides all layers, the second macro selects a specific layer to be shown. Both macros work fine by themselves, but when I try to run the first macro in the second macro I received a compile error, that the sub cannot be found. Any ideas on how to call the private sub correctly?

First sub, which hides all layers:
Private Sub Deselect_layers()

```
Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page
Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape
Dim vsoLayers As Visio.Layers
Dim vsoLayer As Visio.Layer
Set vsoPage = ActivePage
Set vsoLayers = vsoPage.Layers

For Each vsoLayer In vsoLayers
    If vsoLayer.CellsC(visLayerVisible).FormulaU = "1" Then
        vsoLayer.CellsC(visLayerVisible).FormulaU = "0"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Second sub, which shows one specifc layer:

```
Sub Select18()

Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page
Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape
Dim vsoLayers As Visio.Layers
Set vsoPage = ActivePage
Set vsoLayers = vsoPage.Layers

RUNMACRO ("SelectLayers.Deselect_layers")  <-- Error occurs here

vsoLayers.Item("18").CellsC(visLayerVisible).FormulaU = "1"

End Sub
```

What I have tried so far:

```
RUNADDON ("ThisDocument.Deselect_layers")
RUNMACRO ("ThisDocument.Deselect_layers")
Callthis ("ThisDocument.Deselect_layers")
RUNADDON ("ThisDocument.SelectLayers.Deselect_layers")
RUNMACRO ("ThisDocument.SelectLayers.Deselect_layers")
Callthis ("ThisDocument.SelectLayers.Deselect_layers")
```

No of these commands worked. Any help would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Deselect_layers()
    Debug.Print "In Deselect_layers()"
End Sub

Sub Select18()
    Call Deselect_layers
End Sub
```